# Getting entire picture from android gallery programmatically

Tags: android

I there a way to get the entire pictures on you phone gallery, and load it into your app gallery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capiono,

AFAIK there is no intent to get *EVERY* image from the Gallery app

It might perhaps be easier just to do what the Gallery app does and troll your SD Card for directories with images in them.  Don't forget to ignore directories with a file named `.nomedia` at the root.

Cheers

Comment: Please I'm new to android development, how do I get the images from the sdcard? (code sample will be greatly appreciated)   THanks!

Comment: Try: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ExternalStorage.html